# MNIST with Tensorflow and Keras, same architecture but less accurate in Tensorflow

Tags: neural-networks, tensorflow, keras

I implemented a neural network in Keras and Tensorflow to make predictions on the MNIST dataset. I used the same architecture for both Keras and Tensorflow. While the code in Keras gives me always an accuracy on the test set of more than 95%, the code in Tensorflow gives me about 70-80%. Moreover, on the Tensorflow code, if I put num_layers = 5, the accuracy drops to 20%. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code ?

```
# Code in Keras
import keras

# Data
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
X_train = X_train.reshape(-1, 28*28).astype('float32') / 255
X_test = X_test.reshape(-1, 28*28).astype('float32') / 255
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes = 10)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes = 10)

# Model
model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(128, input_dim = 28*28, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.3))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(128, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.3))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10, activation = 'softmax'))

# Training
model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr = 0.001),
              metrics = ['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 5, batch_size = 128,
                    validation_data = (X_test, y_test), verbose = 1)
```

and

```
# Code in Tensorflow
import tensorflow as tf
from math import floor

# Data
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
X_train = X_train.reshape(-1, 28*28).astype('float32') / 255
X_test = X_test.reshape(-1, 28*28).astype('float32') / 255
y_train = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes = 10)
y_test = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes = 10)

# Training parameters
num_classes = 10
num_neurones = 128
num_layers = 5
dropout_kprob = 1 - 0.3
batch_size = 128
epochs = 5
learning_rate = 0.001

# tf Graph input
X = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 28*28])
Y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, num_classes])
dropout = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

# Weights
weights = {}
biases = {}
for i in range(num_layers):
    if (i == 0):
        weights['W_layer_' + str(i)] = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([28*28, num_neurones]))
        biases['b_layer_' + str(i)] = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_neurones]))
    else:
        weights['W_layer_' + str(i)] = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_neurones, num_neurones]))
        biases['b_layer_' + str(i)] = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_neurones]))
weights['out'] = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_neurones, num_classes]))
biases['out'] = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_classes]))

# Model
def model(X):
    prev_X = X
    for i in range(num_layers):
        prev_X = tf.matmul(prev_X, weights['W_layer_' + str(i)]) + biases['b_layer_' + str(i)]
        prev_X = tf.nn.relu(prev_X)
        prev_X = tf.nn.dropout(prev_X, dropout)
    prev_X = tf.matmul(prev_X, weights['out']) + biases['out']
    return prev_X

# Prediction
logits = model(X)
pred = tf.nn.softmax(logits)

# Loss and optimizer
loss_op = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = logits, labels = Y))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = learning_rate)
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss_op)

# Evaluation
correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(Y, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))

# Training
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for i in range(epochs):
        for j in range(floor(len(X_train)/batch_size)):
            batch_x = X_train[j * batch_size : (j + 1) * batch_size]
            batch_y = y_train[j * batch_size : (j + 1) * batch_size]
            sess.run(train_op, feed_dict = {X: batch_x, Y: batch_y, dropout: dropout_kprob})
        test_loss, test_acc = sess.run([loss_op, accuracy], feed_dict = {X: X_test, Y: y_test, dropout: 1})
        print("Epoch " + str(i) + ", Test Loss = " + "{:.4f}".format(test_loss) + \
              ", Testing Accuracy = " + "{:.3f}".format(test_acc))
```

Comment: It looks ok, but keep_prob argument in tf.nn.dropout seems to be deprecated.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the dropout. In the tensorflow code, if I set num_layers to 5, it gave a bad accuracy of 20%. But if I change "dropout: 1" to "dropout: dropout: dropout_kprob" in one of the last lines of the code, I have an accuracy of 85%. Usually, it is better to desactivate the dropout during the evaluation, isn't it the right way to do it in tensorflow? Anyway, if I remove completely the dropout from both Tensorflow and Keras code, I still have a significant better accuracy of 10% in the Keras code when num_layers = 5.

Comment: Maybe try to initialize layers with lower standard deviation, or add batch norm

Comment: agree -- init looks weird

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was indeed the problem.